# SOLVED Material React Table, only one row can be expanded at a time while collapsing others

Tags: reactjs, tanstack, material-react-table

I found a custom solution, but the official site has recently added the native method. I have, however, rewritten the code to use the tables as a reusable tableContainer

```
    import {

    MaterialReactTable,

    useMaterialReactTable,

    } from 'material-react-table';

    import { Box, Typography } from '@mui/material';

    import { data } from './makeData';
```

reusable component
passing props from parent component, for reduce hardcode in
complex table

```
    const Example = ({ columns, data, renderRowSubComponent }) => {

    const table = useMaterialReactTable({
    columns,
    data,
    initialState: { showColumnFilters: true },
    enableExpandAll: false, //disable expand all button

    muiDetailPanelProps: () => ({

      sx: (theme) => ({

        backgroundColor:

          theme.palette.mode === 'dark'

            ? 'rgba(255,210,244,0.1)'

            : 'rgba(0,0,0,0.1)',

      }),

    }),
    //custom expand button rotation

    muiExpandButtonProps: ({ row, table }) => ({

      onClick: () => table.setExpanded({ [row.id]: !row.getIsExpanded() }), //only 1 detail panel open at a time

      sx: {

        transform: row.getIsExpanded() ? 'rotate(180deg)' :  'rotate(-90deg)',

        transition: 'transform 0.2s',

      },

    }),
    //conditionally render detail panel
    renderDetailPanel: ({ row }) => renderRowSubComponent( row ),

    });

  return <MaterialReactTable table={table} />;

};


export default Example;`
```